# Is there a way to prevent MSI Installer from removing a folder during uninstall?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have an application that is wrapped in MSI installer and the app references a folder in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SomeFolder and when I uninstall the app, the SomeFolder gets removed as well. Is there a way I can prevent it from happening? Like, can I exclude this folder from being deleted? My app is a .NET application.

Comment: Why? If your app is being uninstalled, the folder isn't needed any longer. In addition, it's in the user's `Temp` folder, which means it should be temporary in the first place; that's what the `Temp` folder is intended to be used for - temporary files.

Comment: Because my app is moving from MSI to a different type of installer. So if I upgrade my app, it starts using a different installer and I am removing the MSI application. But my upgraded app still needs access to the temp folder to perform some tasks. The problem is, when I run these tasks in the upgraded version, while I perform the MSI uninstall in the background, the tasks fail because the temp folders are removed.